# ruby on rails replace some string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two strings. One is:

`"/system/musics/videos/000/000/001/original/%E5%B9%BF%E5%9C%BA%E8%88%9E%E5%BF%AB%E5%9B%9B_-_%E5%A4%A7%E8%8D%89%E5%8E%9F-%E4%BE%AF%E6%AD%8C.MP3"`

The second one is:

```
"广场舞快四_-_大草原-侯歌.MP3"
```

I want to get:

```
"/system/musics/videos/000/000/001/original/广场舞快四_-_大草原-侯歌.MP3"
```

Does anyone know how to find and replace the string in ruby? My idea is to replace the contents after the last `'/'` with the second string. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with filenames, especially if there is a chance your code will be used on multiple operating systems, use the built-in filename manipulation methods [`dirname`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-dirname) and [`join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-join):

```
File.join(
  File.dirname(
    "/system/musics/videos/000/000/001/original/%E5%B9%BF%E5%9C%BA%E8%88%9E%E5%BF%AB%E5%9B%9B_-_%E5%A4%A7%E8%8D%89%E5%8E%9F-%E4%BE%AF%E6%AD%8C.MP3"
  ),
  "广场舞快四_-_大草原-侯歌.MP3"
)
```

The reason is, `File.join` and `File.dirname` are aware of filename delimiters used on a particular OS, courtesy of `File::SEPARATOR` and `File::ALT_SEPARATOR`, making them able to split and join the paths correctly.

You'll also often find [`File.basename`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-basename) and [`File.extname`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-extname) useful too.

Comment: i can not find the File, i output the string ""/system/musics/videos/000/000/001/original/%E5%B9%BF%E5%9C%BA%E8%88%9E%E5%BF%AB%E5%9B%9B_-_%E5%A4%A7%E8%8D%89%E5%8E%9F-%E4%BE%AF%E6%AD%8C.MP3"" is in views, but i need to change it in controller.

Answer (score 3):

```
first_string = "/system/musics/videos/000/000/001/original/%E5%B9%BF%E5%9C%BA%E8%88%9E%E5%BF%AB%E5%9B%9B_-%E5%A4%A7%E8%8D%89%E5%8E%9F-%E4%BE%AF%E6%AD%8C.MP3"
second_string = "广场舞快四-_大草原-侯歌.MP3"

"#{File.dirname(first_string)}/#{second_string}"
```